# How to solve this trigonometric equation using Casio CFX 9860 series?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, calculator

The equation I'm trying to solve is this:

$$B\times \tan \phi - \frac{1}{2}g \left ( \frac{B}{v_{0}\cos\phi} \right )^{2}=A$$

$\textrm{A and B are constants the unknown is angle phi}$

I don't know if Casio CFX 9860 has the capability to solve such equation. I'm aware that Maple can do the job, but it is not what I'm looking for.

Can somebody help me if there is a program already written for solving this kind of equations.

Let's say if:

$\textrm{A= 16, B= 20}$

$v_{0}=20$

I tried to simplify the equation in such a way that it can be put in terms of one trigonometric expression but the cosine which is in the denominator does seem to be difficult to reduce.

Comment: Use wolfram alpha. It is online and for free. just type in your equation with the fixed patameters and it will automatically solve for $\phi$.

Comment: multiply by cos squared, it becomes a first order differential equation.

Comment: @Jack Thanks for the suggestion but I've only reached to $2A\cos^{2}\phi-B\sin2\phi+\frac{B^{2}g}{v_{0}}=0$, but I don't know how to get the integrating factor from there. Anyway the question was related on if there was any program in CASIO BASIC or anyone already made that can be used to solve the equation as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I have made two approaches to solve this problem, one approach leads to a quartic equation and the other quadratic equation.
$$B\times \tan \phi - \frac{1}{2}g \left ( \frac{B}{v_{0}\cos\phi} \right )^{2}=A\tag{1}$$

---

### Quadratic Equation: $B^2gx^2-2v_0^2Bx+(B^2g+A2v^2)=0$

Where $x=\tan\phi$

Simplifying $(1)$ gives me:
$$B \tan \phi - \frac{gB^2}{2v_0^2\cos^2\phi}=A\Rightarrow B\tan\phi-\frac{gB^2\sec^2\phi}{2v_0^2}$$
Since $\tan^2\phi+1=\sec^2\phi$, then
$$B\tan\phi\cdot2v_0^2-B^2g(\tan\phi+1)=A\cdot2v_0^2$$
$$2v_o^2B\tan\phi-B^2g\tan^2\phi-B^2g-2v_0^2A=0$$
Letting $x=\tan\phi$, we now have a quadratic equation:
$$B^2gx^2-2v_0^2Bx+(B^2g+2v_0^2A)=0$$
$$x\Rightarrow\frac{2v_0^2B\pm\sqrt{(2v_0^2B)^2-4(B^2g)(B^2g+2v_0^2A)}}{2B^2g}$$
And thus:
$$\phi\Rightarrow\tan^{-1}\frac{2v_0^2B\pm\sqrt{(2v_0^2B)^2-4(B^2g)(B^2g+2v_0^2A)}}{2B^2g}$$

---

### Quartic Equation: $(4v_0^4B)x^4-(4AgBv_0^2-4v_0^4B)x^2+(4A^2v_0^4)x-g^2B^2=0$

where $x=\cos \phi$
Simplifying $(1)$ gives me:
$$B\frac{\sin\phi}{\cos\phi}-\frac{gB^2}{2v_0^2\cos^2\phi}=A$$
$$\frac{B\sin\phi\cdot2v_0^2\cos\phi-gB^2}{2v_0^2\cos^2\phi}=A$$
$$B\sin\phi\cdot2v_0^2\cos\phi=gB^2+A\cdot2v_0^2\cos^2\phi\tag{2}$$
Now to eliminate $\sin\phi$, we need to square $(2)$ and thus:
$$4v_0^4\sin^2\phi\cos^2\phi=g^2B^2+4A^2v_0^4\cos^4\phi+4AgBv_0^2\cos^\phi$$
By the Pythagorean identity $\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi=1$, we can rewrite the equation above as:
$$4v_0^4B(1-\cos^2\phi)\cos^2\phi=g^2B^2+4A^2v_0^4\cos^4\phi+4AgBv_0^2\cos^\phi$$
$$4v_0^4B\cos^2\phi-4v_0^4B\cos^4\phi=g^2B^2+4A^2v_0^4\cos^4\phi+4AgBv_0^2\cos^\phi$$
And thus rewriting the equation above, letting $x=\cos\phi$, we have:
$$4v_0^4Bx^4-(4AgBv_0^2-4v_0^4B)x^2+4A^2v_0^4x-g^2B^2=0$$
Maybe then you can use Ferrari's method to solve quartic formulas.

Comment: That's neat. But I still feel that an answer that would incorporate CASIO programming is yet to be written. The particular calculator I mentioned has the capability to solve quadratic equations but maybe not quartic formulas, if you happen to know of a program that can be used with that calculator for that would be nice. I've read about the method you mentioned which reduces it to two quadratic equations which in fact can be solved by CASIO but it was not the straightforward approach that I was looking for.

Comment: You can use the first method where you use $\tan$ instead of squaring the equation. You get a simple solution for $\phi$. However, I do not understand what you are looking for when you want to include the usability of the calculator.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on using the first method. What I was trying to ask was if somebody could show an example of CASIO BASIC programming (which is the native language of that calculator) so that can be used to solve the equation stated. In the user's manual there is a guide but I do not know how to make a program to solve let's say quartic equations to find their roots. Again the Ferrari method you mentioned got me interested into looking if there are other exotic methods to find the roots of higher degree equations.

Comment: I have no knpwledge with programmable calculators. You can always work by hand and have the calculator solve a, for example, quadratic equation. Bear in mind that polynomials with degrees higher than  have no analytic solution. Your best course of action is to use numerical methods such as newton"s method, regula falsi, secant method etc.